# Potentiometer Working

Tags: potentiometer, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

Let's suppose that \$E \gt V\$. Now, the voltage \$V_b\$ at point \$b\$ will always be \$V\$ and will not depend on \$E\$.

Similarly the voltage \$V_A\$ at point \$A\$ is \$V_E\$ which will be negative in order to make potential difference across the galvanometer wire equal to \$V\$.

My question is that why, at point \$b\$, \$E\$ has no effect on \$V_b\$?

Also, is it true that if \$E>V\$ then the current will be supplied by \$E\$ and not \$V\$?

The potential at c =0

Comment: Please make a distinction between voltage and potential. You didn't define a zero potential (aka ground) so you can't say the *voltage* at point x is V.

Comment: Are you sure the second rheostat (the component with Rh) should be in your circuit? It looks to me the red component between the points b and c is the rheostat you're question is about.

Comment: @Huisman the potential at c =0

Comment: I wanted to say what Huisman did say. Where is the ground? I don't think, I ever calculated voltages at different nodes, without first defining a ground. You say at c=0, but you didn't show it in your circuit diagram. Also just for my understanding, what is `A1`? Is it a constant current source?

Comment: @DuckDodgers A1 ammeter with negligible resistance.

Comment: @DuckDodgers it was a theoretical question which stated - take potential at C to be 0

Comment: @Who, `:)`. Yes, I am all for theoretical questions, but if I remember the circuit analysis course from my 2nd semester at the university back in 2004, correctly, first step of doing any sort of nodal voltage anaylsis was by first adding a ground to the circruit (usually the node which has the most branches). I maybe wrong though. My memory is a bit rusty. `:)`

Comment: "*... Vb  at point b will always be V and will not depend on E.*" No, that's only true when the circuit is balanced and \$ I_{A1}\$ = 0. If there is a current flowing through \$ R_h \$ then \$ V_b \neq V \$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A1 and Rh are an ammeter with negligible resistance, we can ignore them.  Does seem a strange assumption since ammeters have shunt resistors in parallel, but an ammeter  has negligible resistance.  It has to be to get a valid answer to OP's question.  As the BJT said **If there is a current flowing through \$R_h\$ then \$V_b\$ ≠ V.**

You also have a Galvanometer G, which essentially is an ammeter with negligible resistance.  Again ignored.

> Also, is it true that if E > V then the current will be supplied by E and not V?

Yes & No.  Both sources will supply current to the circuit, but since \$R_{bA}\$ is in parallel with E (across the terminals), E is the only supplier of current to \$R_{bA}\$.  It does not matter whether E > V, E = V or E < V.

> My question is that why, at point b, E has no effect on Vb?

It is how V is connected to b & c.  If you look at the circuit, c = 0V, so potential across \$R_{bc}\$, \$V_{bc}\$ = V.  b & c are across the terminals of V.  No resistors to drop potential.  Again, relationship between E & V is irrelevant.

Not a part of the question but there are three cases:

- If E > V, then \$V_{Ac}\$ is negative (relative to c).  OP question.
- If E = V, then \$V_{Ac}\$ = 0 and no current flows in \$R_{bc}\$.
- If E < V, then \$V_{Ac}\$ is positive.

This is the only voltage which changes in the circuit.